# View to View data binding between a ContentPage and ContentView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, view, binding

View to View data binding between a ContentPage and ContentView

I'm using the PlaneRotationDemoPage sample from the Xamarin Forms Book https://download.xamarin.com/developer/xamarin-forms-book/XamarinFormsBook-Ch21-Apr2016.pdf

I have a ContentPage and want to move a Slider control from the ContentPage into a ContentView that is in a different XAML/CS file. The content view itself seems to be referenced correctly, however the Slider control binding doesn't seem to be wired correctly. I get an error "Can't resolve name on Element"

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlaneRotationDemo;assembly=PlaneRotationDemo"
         x:Class="PlaneRotationDemo.PlaneRotationDemoPage" >
...

<local:RoundedBoxView x:Name="handA"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        CornerRadius = "40"
        Stroke = "White"
        Color = "Gray"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds = "152.0,248.0,15.0,15.0"
    />

...

<local:SliderTest /> //new ContentView


//Moving just the slider below into a ContentView   
<!--    
<Slider x:Name="rotationSlider"  
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds = "0,0,200,50"
        Maximum="360"
        Value="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=handA},
        Path=Rotation}"
        />-->

//the label below on the ContentPage should bind with the slider that was moved to the ContentView

<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference rotationSlider},
    Path=Value,
    StringFormat='Rotation = {0:F0}'}"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    />
```

In the ContentView file...

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="PlaneRotationDemo.SliderTest">
<ContentView.Content>

//slider moved here
<Slider x:Name="rotationSlider"
        Maximum="360"
        Value="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=handA}, //should bind with handA in the ContentPage
        Path=Rotation}"
        />

</ContentView.Content>
```

The label in the ContentPage needs to reference the slider that is now in the ContentView

The Slider that is now in the ContentView needs to reference the handA RoundedBoxView that is in the ContentPage

Is this possible in XAML?

Answer (score 2):

Expose a **BindableProperty** in User Control (Content View). Bind **BindableProperty** to Value property in Slider Control.

And XAML looks like this.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="PlaneRotationDemo.SliderTest" x:Name=UC>
<ContentView.Content>

//slider moved here
<Slider x:Name="rotationSlider"
        Maximum="360"
        Value="{Binding MyBindableProperty, Source={x:Reference Name=UC},
        Path=Rotation}"/>

</ContentView.Content>
```

And usage will be like this.

```
<local:RoundedBoxView x:Name="handA"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        CornerRadius = "40"
        Stroke = "White"
        Color = "Gray"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds = "152.0,248.0,15.0,15.0"
    />

<local:SliderTest MyBindableProperty={Binding Source={x:Reference handA}}/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Xaml it creates a cs and an autogenerated cs(xaml.g.cs) file that your x:Name references defined there. Since handA is not defined your SliderTest.xaml file you're getting this error.

Comment: I tried adding xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlaneRotationDemo;assembly=PlaneRotationDemo" to the header in the SliderTest.Xaml but how to add to the binding? Value="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=local:handA} didn't work with the addition of local:handA